# Vue project(vue-cli 3/4) lazy loading route can not reach static file when I host static files on CDN

Tags: vue.js

for example:

- host my page on https://my-site.com/my-path/
- set publicPath of vue.config.js to /my-path/
- host static files on https://static.my-site.com/

when I use lasy loading route, the route try to load files on https://my-site.com/my-path/js/xxxxx.js,
but my static files are hosted on https://static.my-site.com,so it raise a 404 problem.

how can I solve this.

Comment: What should be the path to your static assets? Is it `https://static.my-site.com/js/xxxxx.js` or `https://static.my-site.com/my-path/js/xxxxx.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things to do here...

1. Set your `publicPath` to the static site base URL

   ```js
   // vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
       ? "https://static.my-site.com/"
       : "/"
   }
   ```
2. Set your router's `base` to the base path of your app

   ```js
   import Vue from "vue"
   import VueRouter from "vue-router"

   Vue.use(VueRouter)

   const router = new VueRouter({
     base: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
       ? "/my-path/"
       : "/",
     routes: [...]
   })
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the absolute locations in the **import** statements